# how to log model inserts,updates and deletes in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to log model inserts,updates and deletes?
I am not using django admin,in my app there are multiple tables
i just want to records only which  model or table name, field name,previous value,who edited,and what time
to  log table?

Who edited (my app uses SSO,it should pick up remote user automatically)

can you please suggest any built in function or module in django to records this kind of logs ,if possible can you plz add few lines of django code or any ref links?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def logging_function(sender, **kwargs):
   # do your logging

post_save.connect(logging_function)
```

Comment: i think,i need to pre_save,but i have a model called logs ,how to insert updated fields modelname,fieldname,value,who,what into log model,can you add few line of code

Comment: This doesn't handle bulk updates with queryset.update() for which there is no signal. And it doesn't handle the case where raw SQL is used (which might be a nitpick, but might be important to keep in mind in some apps!).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a logger  http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html  What's wrong with that?

You can, also, add an event table to your Django models and write to that table.

For real fun, you can create a decorator which writes to that table.

You can search, too.  You'll find things like this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2111/